# Index DataFrame values until a value/string is reached

Tags: python, excel, oracle

I have an Excel spreadsheet and I would like to export the essential data from it into my Oracle table.

The Excel sheet has extra unnecessary data in certain cells though. It also splits halfway thru, indicating a difference between available fish and desired fish. I need to capture this difference.

So my goal is to export ALL of the data, but in my Oracle Database I need to differentiate between offered fish and desired fish. So is there a way to index the columns until the index reaches `QUOTA TO BUY`? Therefore allowing me to export the first chunk with a `1` in my `ask` column, and export the second chunk with a `1` in my `bid` column.

The code I've tried so far is below, as well as a picture of the Excel table. Thanks for any help.

[image]

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
import re
from dateutil import parser

dsnStr = cx_Oracle.makedsn("sole.noaa.gov", "1526", "sole")
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user="user", password="passsword", dsn=dsnStr)

path = 'Z:\\excel_file_to_convert'

#pattern = re.compile(r'Sent:(.+?)(?=<br/>)')

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
        print("df is:", df)
        print("column 1 I think:", df[:DESIRED STOCK])
        print("row 1:", df.loc[0])
        print("row 2:", df.loc[1])
        print("row 3:", df.loc[2])
        print("row 4:", df.loc[3])
        print("row 5:", df.loc[4])

        #d = parser.parse(df, fuzzy=True)
        #print(d)        

        #df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])         # convert date column to datetimes 
        #latest_date = df['DATE'].max()                 # find the latest datetime
        #latest_rows = df[df['DATE'] == latest_date]     # use index filtering to choose only columns equal to latest date
        #print ("latest_rows is:", latest_rows)



cursor = con.cursor()
exported_data = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
sql_query = ("INSERT INTO ROUGHTABLE(species, date_posted, stock_id, pounds, money, sector, ask)" "VALUES(:3, :1, :2, :4, :5, 'Sustainable Harvest Sector', '1')")

#sql_query = ("INSERT INTO DATABASE(species, trade_date, trade_id, pounds, advertised_price, email_year, email_month, email_day, sector, ask)" "VALUES(:3, :1, :2, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, 'Sustainable Harvest Sector', '1')")
cursor.executemany(sql_query, exported_data)
con.commit() #commit to database

cursor.close()
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to do this repeatedly then you don't need to use an additional language.

Paste this into cell `F4` and copy it down to all the rows you want to insert in the first block.

```
="INSERT INTO ROUGHTABLE(date_posted, stock_id, species, pounds, money, sector, ask) VALUES ( DATE '"&YEAR(A4)&"-"&MONTH(A4)&"-"&DAY(A4)&"', "&B4&", '"&C4&"', '"&D4&"', "&E4&", 'Sustainable Harvest Sector', '1' );"
```

Copy and paste the generated SQL statements into a script and run it in SQL/Plus.

You can then edit the formula for the second block and repeat the process as appropriate.

Comment: I do need to do this repeatedly though....does that mean this bit of SQL code won't work on other Excel sheets?

Comment: You can copy and paste it into multiple spreadsheets if they are all the same format. Just edit the that need editing (like the `sector` or `ask`/`bid` columns) so that it is correct for each sheet. If you are doing it for a handful of sheets then it will work but if you are doing it for hundreds or doing it every week then it might be worth spending the time to write a programmatic solution like you have started.

Comment: Hmm ok. I have to do it for about 120, and then once a week after that. So I guess ideally I'd like to have the program do it. Honestly, most of the spreadsheets don't have that split between `Available` and `Desired` so I'm just going to enter this one by hand probably. But the issue I'm running into now is I need that date that always follows `LISTING` in the first cell, so I figure I'll RegEx for it but I'm not great with RegEx so this is taking a while. Then I'll need to tackle capturing all the essential data but getting rid of those first two title cells